# Rendering a tiledMap in a specific position

Tags: java, libgdx, tiled

I was wondering if there was a way to render an orthographic Tiled Map in a specific (x,y) position

This is the code I am currently using to draw my Tiled Map at position (0,0)

```
//In Constructor  
tileMap = new TmxMapLoader().load(mapAddress);  
tmr = new OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer(tileMap, 1/4f);

//In Render Method  
tmr.setView(camera)   
tmr.render();
```

I tried to use the second constructor for setView(), but it didn't work.

Thanks in advance for the help

Jo1430905

Answer (score 0):

You could use `camera.translate(x, y)` to move the camera around instead of actually translating the TiledMap.